# Typescript div,br and &nbsp; I don't want the tags to be displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
  const handleSettingRuleChange = (value?: any) => {
if (formState?.errors?.message) trigger('message')
setValue('message', value)
console.log('Greeting->' + defaultValues.message);
const vl: string = value.replace("<div>&nbsp;<br></div>", " ")
console.log('handleSettingRuleChange->' + vl)}
```

The output of this code is as follows. div br and   I don't want the tags to be displayed. Even though I replaced it, it didn't go away.
how can i fix this

example log:

```
handleSettingRuleChange->alperen&nbsp;<div><br></div><div>kapusuz</div><div>dfasf</div><div>&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: the replace you are doing is looking for the exact string `<div>&nbsp;<br></div>` that isn't there in what you showed in the example log. So what are you exactly trying to achieve? you want to remove tags opening and closing? you want to remove empty divs?

Comment: the incoming value is div, br and &nbsp; I want to send backend without tags.
this is what i'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not perfectly clear all the possibilities you may encounter in that input string so to make sure that it will always work returning exactly the text content, you may just create a temporary element and fill its `innerHTML` with that string so that when fetching its `textContent` you will be returned the exact text content as it would be when the html was rendered.

But since `.textContent` won't automatically count `<br>` elements as new lines, you may need to process the html element and all its children recursively and if any node found is of type `BR` just return a new line.

I edited the answer so that now it takes ***br*** into account.

I used `.childNodes` instead of `.children` because I want all children to be visited, including nodes that are just `text nodes` and not only html elements.

I used reduce to come up with a single string result from a given array -the children nodes.

### References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```js
const input = 'alperen&nbsp;<div><br></div><div>kapusuz</div><div>dfasf</div><div>&nbsp;</div>';

console.log( returnTextContent(input) ); //alperen\NEWLINEkapusuzdfasf

//creates a temp div element with the given html as its content and returns its rendered text content
function returnTextContent(html){
  const tempContainer = document.createElement('div');  
  tempContainer.innerHTML = html;
  return getTextContent(tempContainer);  
}

//walks through node and its children to return its text content
function getTextContent(node){    
  //if node is of type <BR> returns newline
  if(node.tagName == 'BR')
    return "\n";
  //else if node has no children returns its .textContent
  if(node.childNodes.length == 0)
    return node.textContent;     
  //else return the concatenated text content of its children
  return [...node.childNodes].reduce(
    (textContent, child) => { return textContent += getTextContent(child) }, "");  
}
```

Comment: this worked but only one issue remained.
it just takes it as a single line.
I want it to go to the bottom line.
how can i fix this

Comment: I edited the answer so that now instead of just returning textContent, it first goes through all its children recursively and correctly addresses the case in which there's a `<br>` element to return it as a newline

Comment: @DiegoD Or just replace `<br>` for `\n` in input HTML and use original approach.

Comment: @JanPfeifer can you run the risk to encounter an html string containng the `<br>` token not being the expected element? It's pretty rare like having an attribute containing that value. But I didn't see conditions strict enough to run such risk and I usually avoid breaking the encoding rules for transforming encoded entities.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to replace exact string `<div>&nbsp;<br></div>`. Replace particular tags:

```
.replaceAll('<div>', ' ').replaceAll('</div>', ' ').replaceAll('<br>', ' ').replaceAll('&nbsp;', ' ');
```

Comment: i tried this but i still get the same error

Comment: @AlperenKapusuz my bad. Change `replace` to `replaceAll`.

Comment: sorry i tried but it doesn't work